# okta 400 after deployed in IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-mvc, okta

I have deployed my WebApplication in IIS. After that when I browse my application, I am getting 400 Bad Request. But when I'm running on Debug mode or Release mode from the Visual studio there is no issue.

My application is  .ASP.Net core and Integrated with okta authentication

Here is a screenshot of the error I'm getting:
[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: It is not a page from either IIS or ASP.NET Core. So you should dig where it comes from first.